# How do I remove the restriction of 'Permission denied', when using the 'mkdir' command in Git Bash?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, git-bash, permission-denied, mkdir

When inputting 'mkdir Thinkful' to the command-line, I get the following message:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Thinkful’: Permission denied

I recently downloaded git version 2.37.3.windows.1 and I am using Windows 10. I have Developer Mode 'ON' in my settings, as well as, all of the default options chosen for Git Bash upon install. I have looked through other similar problems on stackoverflow, but have not found a solution to my problem.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your user need to have write permission on the current directory.

You can find more on linux administration here for example:
https://www.youtube.com/c/tutoriaLinux?app=desktop